# JTable проблема с сортировкой

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Есть проблема с сортировкой колонки с использованием символа валюты,
если мы задаем валюту в рендере:

```
public class CurrencyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private DecimalFormat format;

    public CurrencyRenderer() {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if (format == null) {
            format = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)");
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : format.format(value));
    }
}
```

то все хорошо, но как быть если мы задаем символ динамически? Когда задаем динамически, то приходит value в виде `Object[] value`, где `value[0]` - это значение, и `value[1]` - это символ, но с таким видом получаемых значений столбец у нас сортируется как `Object[]`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `TableRowSorter` есть метод [`setComparator( int column, Comparator<?>comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setComparator-int-java.util.Comparator-), который позволяет указать, как сравнивать значения в столбце. Если делать через массив, то будет что-то такое:

```
    // отмазка: я знаю, что хранить деньги, как число с плавающей точкой - плохо,
    // но в примере сойдет.
    Object[][] rowData = {
            { "строка 1", new Object[] {100.50d, "руб"} },
            { "строка 2", new Object[] {5d, "$"} },
            { "строка 3", new Object[] {89.99d, "\u20A4"} },
            { "строка 4", new Object[] {-8d, "$"} },
            { "строка 5", new Object[] {1000d, "$"} },
            { "строка 6", new Object[] {1d, "руб"} },
    };
    Object[] columnNames = { "caption", "currency" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel( rowData, columnNames );
    JTable table = new JTable( model );
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 1 ).setCellRenderer( new CurrencyRenderer() );

    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>( model );
    // реализация компаратора
    sorter.setComparator( 1, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 ) {
            Object[] record1 = (Object[])o1;
            Object[] record2 = (Object[])o2;

            // сначала сравниваются валюты (как строки)
            int result = ((String)record1[1]).compareTo( (String)record2[1] );
            // если валюты одинаковые, то значения сумм (как Double)
            return result != 0 ? result : ((Double)record1[0]).compareTo( (Double)record2[0]);
        }
    });

    table.setRowSorter( sorter );
```

Из-за работы с массивом получается ужас и приведения типов. Стоит задуматься о вынесении денег в отдельный класс:

```
public static class Money {
    String currency;
    Double value;

    public Money( Double value, String currency ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String currency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public Double value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Тогда в Java 8 можно создать компаратор с тем же поведением так:

```
Comparator<Money> comparator = Comparator.comparing( Money::currency ).thenComparing( Money::value );
```

Еще этот класс может поддерживать интерфейс `Comparable`, и тогда `TableRowSorter` будет использовать `compareTo`. Для этого еще понадобится переопределить `tableModel.getColumnClass( int column )`, чтобы он возвращал `Money.class` для нужного столбца.